# C++20 P0784R7 Non-transient allocation too brittle vs. P1004R2 constexpr std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, constexpr, c++20

I would like to create an extensive `constexpr` data repository in C++20. Tens of thousands of hopefully native C++ objects loaded as "text segment" i.e. demand paged into the process and shared between instances (the code is generated).

The objects are referencing each other and need indexing by various properties, cross-referencing etc. all hopefully done at compile time. This calls for `constexpr` (associative) containers, but it can't be done with templatized (by size, hash size, etc.) containers, as everything needs to remain polymorphic.

First it seems impossible, as C++20 [P0784R7](https://wg21.link/P0784R7) says that non-transient allocation is too brittle, i.e. dynamically allocated memory is not allowed to be leaked out of `constexpr` evaluations.

At the same time C++20 [P1004R2](https://wg21.link/P1004R2) says that `constexpr std::vector` is to be supported. In the latter paper I see all members, including the modification members marked as `constexpr`. So unless I'm missing something, I can add elements to `std::vectors` inside `constexpr` evaluations (compilers don't support it yet, so I can't try).

```
// 21.3.11.5, modifiers
template<class... Args> constexpr reference emplace_back(Args&&... args);
constexpr void push_back(const T& x);
constexpr void push_back(T&& x);
...
```

But then why can't I build an `allocator<T>` around a `std::vector<T>` and still have non-transient allocations? Aren't the two capabilities "computationally equivalent" i.e. `constexpr std::vector` *needs* non-transient allocation to be implemented, and therefore it can also *provide it*?

And when will compilers *finally* support it?
... or is this suspected contradiction even the reason for the delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of transient allocations. Transient allocations are allocations that exist *entirely* within constant evaluation. For example:

```
constexpr std::size_t summation(std::vector<unsigned int> const &vi)
{
  std::size_t ret = 0;
  for(auto i : vi)
    ret += i;
  return ret;
}

constexpr auto sum = summation({20, 44, 98});
```

In the call of `summation`, the ultimate input source (the braced-init-list and its values) is known entirely at compile time. Yes, there is a `vector`, but this exists *entirely* within the constant expression evaluation. The `vector` object is used to compute the constant value, but the `vector` itself never leaves constant expression code.

This kind of allocation, one that exists entirely within constant evaluation, is called a "transient allocation". Such allocations are permitted under C++20's rules.

A non-transient allocation would be data "loaded as 'text segment'", and that is what isn't allowed. So your first impression is correct.

Comment: The intention is to use std::vectors as class members, computed in constructors etc.

Comment: ... or as a static variable. Are you saying that this is not covered by P1004R2? Why? Where do I see that in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr ?

Comment: @markus: "*Why?*" Because it would require non-transient allocations, which are *not allowed*. Allocations created within a constant expression context cannot leak out into non-constant expression contexts. That's the rule, as I explained in my answer. And that is mentioned in the [documentation of the *one* allocation function that you can call at compile-time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate).

Comment: So to sum it up (re the initial question) P0784R7 is enforced on top of P1004R2. And there is nothing in the interface declaration of a type such as std::string or std::vector that warns you against that. More specifically the nice-sounding constexpr promise of P1004R2 (and P0980R1 for std::string) or for that matter any constexpr (constructor) declaration does not guarantee that you can actually construct something for a static constexpr variable. 

Regarding what I have hoped to achieve, the sobering truth is that I'm stuck with C arrays and C string literals.

Comment: @markus: There's nothing in the "interface declaration of ... std::string or std::vector" that tells you they allocate memory *at all*. So why would you expect this additional property of its memory allocation behavior to be part of its interface?

Comment: because it is constexpr declared. The official promise is "Such variables and functions can then be used where only compile time constant expressions are allowed (provided that appropriate function arguments are given)". For a constructor or return type my reasonable assumption was that this relates to "what is constructed" or returned i.e. including the memory allocated for members. If allocation is not allowed by the language, then such a constructor or function should not be allowed to be declared constexpr, because it turns out "such variables and functions cannot be used".

Comment: @markus: It *is allowed*; the code I posted will work. It simply is not allowed in the circumstances you're trying to do it. You can put such things in an object during constant evaluation, but that type *must not leak* into non-constant evaluated code. The barrier is not about the types, but the *uses* of the type. That is, whether the code is valid depends on *how you use it*.