# Is it possible to do an aligned alllocation in a constexpr context?

Tags: c++, simd, constexpr, memory-alignment

I have some code that requires a vector to be SIMD aligned and I'm using an aligned allocator from a library as an allocator to implement that, but this allocator has no constexpr support. Would it be possible to use constexpr new and delete to make an aligned allocator? I don't actually have to perform SIMD operations in the constexpr context, but I would like to be able to constexpr construct the types to run a couple of static assert tests without having duplicate code.

Let's say the compile time test looks like something like this:

```
constexpr std::vector<float, AlignedAllocator<float>> vector = { 0.f, 1.f, 2.f };
static_assert(vector.size() == 3);
```

But the runtime code uses the same vector type to perform SIMD operations requiring the actual alignment of the allocator. The allocator could be non-standard conforming because I am using something else than an actual vector in the actual code, but the idea stays the same that memory should be aligned for runtime use. The main requirement I'm trying to address is that I would like to have the same container type at runtime as the one being used in the constant evaluated context (where no SIMD operations are performed).

Comment: Do you need it to be dynamic allocation, rather than automatic storage like `alignas(16) int foo[4];`?

Comment: If it’s all in constexpr context, why would you care how it’s aligned?

Comment: C++ does not support non-transient compile-time dynamic allocations yet. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222089/c20-p0784r7-non-transient-allocation-too-brittle-vs-p1004r2-constexpr-stdve)

Comment: I need it to be aligned because some of the runtime code requires it to be aligned, and yes it has to be dynamic allocation size is unknown. I don't need non-transient allocation, when I will run in constant evaluation the memory will be deallocated within constexpr context. I basically want to run constexpr tests on part of the code, without having to change the allocator type for runtime use.

Comment: It is known at compile time, but it cannot be in the type's template arguments, otherwise I would end up with duplicate code for the runtime use case again.

Comment: *size is unknown* - Then how can your code work?  The size has to be known at allocation time, and if that time is while evaluating a constexpr, the size must also be constexpr.  Therefore you can use a plain array even if the size is a "variable" that comes from an arg to a constexpr function evaluated in a constexpr context.  Or is the problem that you want to use the same code in non-constexpr contexts, and it involves allocating temporary buffers for some reason instead of just doing SIMD stuff over inputs?

Comment: Note that Intel's SIMD intrinsics aren't `constexpr`, unfortunately, even though things like `_mm_add_epi32` certainly could be, just like the C++ `+` operator.  So if you're targeting x86 with manually-vectorized code using intrinsics, static_assert is probably a non-starter.  GNU C native vectors might work, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes With C++20 you can now do dynamic allocations with `new` and so on (with some limitations which the question is about). The size for such allocations doesn't need to be itself a `constexpr` as long is it is calculated during the evaluation of the constant expression.

Comment: I don't know if this answer is dump or not, but perhaps you could allocate extra space and advance the pointer and align it yourself?

Comment: @user17732522: Is a constant expression like `2 * size` involving only `constexpr` inputs not the same thing as being `constexpr`?  Certainly to fully evaluate something in a static_assert, everything including all allocation sizes need to be available for compile-time eval, regardless of terminology.

Comment: @PeterCordes "being `constexpr`" probably doesn't have a clear meaning, but I would understand it as being declared `constexpr` which has varying meanings in the language. But regarding the bigger picture, I understand that OP just wants to use the vectors inside `static_assert`s for some tests. These tests don't require any runtime input and can use dynamic allocation. (For example `static_assert(std::vector{1,3,4}.size() == 3);` is valid C++20.)

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe Are you talking about an `std::vector` or some custom vector implementation? Is the allocator supposed to be conforming to the standard libraries allocator concept or what exactly are the requirements. One thing you can't do in a constant expression is cast between pointer types. Returning anything `void*` from the allocator is therefore not going to be usable in a a constant expression. Otherwise however, I don't see why it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe: Can you show a [mcve] of one of the functions you're hoping to create a `static_assert` test for, and of the hoped-for static_assert?  If the allocation size is always small, and you're targeting GNU C, you could use a variable-length array if the same code has to work with runtime-variable size inputs when not called in a constexpr.  (Under 1kiB or so, using stack space is totally fine and good, nothing to worry about as long as you sanity-check the input to avoid exploits with huge allocations.)

Comment: In C++17, `std::vector<over_aligned_type>` will do aligned allocations for you, but that would mean making a vector of `__m128` or something, not `float`.  A typedef of float with alignment would at worst not work, or at best compile with *each* float being padded to 16 bytes, not just the first one.  So yeah, C++17 didn't remove the need for a custom allocator in many cases, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm now starting to think I could maybe switch between aligned and non-aligned allocation based on if(std::is_constant_evaluated()) in the allocator type since the allocated memory have to be released in the constexpr context either way.